# Should we merge two functions in JavaScript if they perform the same task?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Hi I have some JavaScript functions in my project. These functions mostly are setting html tag values as true or false.
 Are these operations as per Standard programming practice. How to refactor such functions?

```js
function first(){
      if(myArray[questionIndex] ==1)
        var question = "true";
      else
         question = "false";    
      
            firstStr = firstStr + '<flag isFlagged="' + question + '" />';

    }

    function second() {  
      if(myArray[questionIndex] ==1)
        var question = "true";
      else
        question = "false";    
      
            secondStr = secondStr + '<flag isFlagged="' + question + '" />';

    }
```

My Question is should I merge it and assign the functions to a variable and return the value like this

```js
var resultValue(){
  if(myArray[questionIndex] ==1)
    return "true";
  else
    return "false";

}

function first(){
  var question = resultValue();     
            firstStr = firstStr + '<flag isFlagged="' + question + '" />';

    }

function second() {
  var question = resultValue();       
            secondStr = secondStr + '<flag isFlagged="' + question + '" />';

    }
```

What is the optimized solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: One function with an argument

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's up to you to keep multiple functions performing 'the same' task or refractor them into one function. The purpose of merging is to help you easier maintain the code in the long run, and make your code somehow cleaner.

In case of merging your code, it would be something like this:

```
function func(str){
      if(myArray[questionIndex] ==1)
        var question = "true";
      else
         question = "false";    

            str = str + '<flag isFlagged="' + question + '" />';
return str;
    }
```

Then you can call that function like this:

```
firstStr = func(firstStr);
secondStr = func(secondStr);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function result(str) {
  var resultValue = ""
  if (myArray[questionIndex] === 1)
    resultValue = "true";
  else
    resultValue = "false";    
  return str + '<flag isFlagged="' + str + '" />';
}
```

Also, you can define some alias:

```
function first() { firstStr = result(firstStr); }
function second() { secondStr = result(secondStr); }
```